# Trouble saving integer fields in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have some trouble creating a new model with column type integer. After posting from a form, they the field ends up with `nil`.

For testing purposes, I tried making a new application and new scaffold named "User".

```
rails g scaffold User username:string password:string type:integer
```

I went to the form and entered `1` into the field for the integer. In the database it ended up with nil. I tried debugging `@user` straight after and it was also `nil`. `params[:user]` showed `type => 1`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I just found out the problem. Apparently the word 'type' is reserved for columns that's why it wasn't working.

I renamed the column from type to user_type and now it is working happily without any modifications. Silly me.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `params[:user][:type]` is a string, which you need to convert to an integer.

```
params[:user][:type].to_i
```

Comment: Ah I see, I was wondering this also. However I expected the scaffold code to work out of the box...

Comment: I'm still getting the same problem even with a to_i fix. I checked in irb and the type of params[:user][:type] is now irb(#<UsersController:0x60a0f38>):002:0> num.class
=> Fixnum

Comment: This isn't working in the scaffold code, so it is just simply: @user = User.new(params[:user])

After checking on @user using debugger, @user.type = nil

I added params[:user][:type].to_i above that line and it didn't make any difference.